# Typescript: Merging union of records into a single record?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to perform the following type transformation? I've been experimenting with Mapped types, and I don't think it's actually possible... hoping to be wrong though.

```
{
  foo: 'bar',
  type: 'A'
} |
{
  foo: 'car',
  type: 'B',
}
```

into

```
{
  bar: 'A',
  car: 'B'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a mapped type to map from each `foo` value to its corresponding `type` value.  The type `Values<Pick<Base, 'foo'>>` gives you the union of all the keys while `Extract<Base, { foo: P }>['type']` finds the matching `type` for a given key `P`.

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Base = {
   foo: 'bar',
   type: 'A'
}
   |
{
   foo: 'car',
   type: 'B',
}

type Result = {
   [P in Values<Pick<Base, 'foo'>>]: Extract<Base, { foo: P }>['type']
}
```

Comment: @Linda Paiste Thank You very much

Answer (score 2):

There's an alternative solution that also works if the `Base` type has more than two alternatives (**update**: this was written before the other solution got edited, now they both work), e.g.:

```
type Base =
  {foo: 'bar', type: 'A'} | {foo: 'car',type: 'B'} | {foo: 'd',type: 'C'}
```

It requires a utility type `TypeForFoo` that returns the type of `foo` for a foo-type object, so `TypeForFoo<Base, 'car'>` equals `'B'`:

```
type TypeForFoo<B, F> = B extends {foo: F, type: infer T} ? T : never
```

This works because the conditional type distributes over the union, meaning that it is applied to each of the alternatives of `Base`, after which the results are combined in a union (so the `never`'s disappear).

With `TypeForFoo`, the final object type can be written as

```
type Obj = {[F in Base['foo']]: TypeForFoo<Base, F>}
// inferred: Obj = {bar: 'A', car: 'B', d: 'C'}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwGYHssC4oDkARnAE4EA0Uok+BAggQL5QA+62ehAxmZTRDoxmbDjjoATfuEGEAwswCwAKBUCoAFRkAxLKV1YAPDCraAfFFQwoEAB7AIAOwkIxXbVQH4Alo4wRSTRYAfk0ofEcIADcAtRlNCARgS00dPQNjRAgqAl5yCwB6Aqhff1JSCAl8DUTk1AJhFTjIKAB5IgArFLQAbW0Sx1gsnoJOAgBdceq0-RxMpFMzJhUigbKKqrbO7pJSOkYqPKFKKE2CBWXlIA)

Comment: I like your solution more than mine. You have my upvote!

Comment: Haha, thanks! Actually your solution isn't bad at all (I hadn't realized it was just a typo) so let me return the favor. Next time maybe write the explanation yourself though :-)

Comment: Honestly, I'm to lazy to write explanation. I know it is bad )